# Assembly Reference Issue in Xamarin.iOS Project

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, fody-propertychanged

> MTOUCH: error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void
>   PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute::.ctor()" reference
>   from "MvvmCross.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null"

Following errors are from Compiling Environment
 Mono Framework 4.8.1
 Xamarin Studio 6.3(863)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when the FodyWeavers.xml file's build action was set to "none" instead of "Content".

Comment: still getting above mentioned error in build compiling.
@De11aZ

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my PCL was referencing the wrong `Newtonsoft.JSON` version.

I uninstalled and reinstalled `Fody` and `PropertyChanged.Fody` packages. This resolved the issue for me by correcting the references.